# VB.NET order binance keep getting error 400

Tags: api, http-status-code-400, binance

I am trying to post a sell order using the binance API.  I have no clue what I am doing wrong but I keep getting the error 400. command issue, but when I compare it to the binance examples I don't see the difference...  The code :

Private Sub BinanceOrder2(ByVal aantal As String, ByVal munt As String, ByVal prijs As String, ByVal type As String)

Dim TimeStamp As String = CLng((DateTime.UtcNow - #1970/01/01#).TotalMilliseconds).ToString

```
    Try
        Dim TotalParam As String
        TotalParam = "symbol=XLMUSDT&side=SELL&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=5&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=" & TimeStamp

        Dim HashKey As String
        HashKey = HashString(TotalParam, SecretKey)

        Dim APIUrl As String
        APIUrl = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order/test?" + TotalParam + "&signature=" + HashKey
        Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Request = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(APIUrl), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        Request.Method = "POST"
        Request.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", APIKey)

        Dim Response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(Request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse) '
        Dim Read = New System.IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream).ReadToEnd
        rtxtReply.Text = Read
        rtxtReply.Refresh()

    Catch ex As Exception
        rtxtReply.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.ToString
    End Try
End Sub
```

The hashkey function works as I can access my wallet etc.
I have spent so many time figuring this one out but no succes so far.
I appreciate any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
Second issue : UTC time of pc was 1600 ms off with binance server time. I wrote a time syncro sub and it now works like a charm.